# Deployed Meteor app always returns an HTML file

Tags: nginx, meteor, upstart

I deployed my meteor application using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx) guide, which walks you through nginx setup and writing an Upstart script. Everything works well - I can see that the server is running through the logs in MongoDB. However, making any kind of http request to the app returns an HTML file which looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/936d1dcb9d4c6f9e2d068003929d00edaea39a87.css?meteor_css_resource=true">
            <script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"meteorRelease":"METEOR@1.0.3.2","ROOT_URL":"http://appname.myserver.com","ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"","autoupdateVersion":"3fffc72460404bce55af5963e369702ab5a1a85f","autoupdateVersionRefreshable":"7fbcbd377f48fbf1ff3e288e433b9b5bdb25d6dd","autoupdateVersionCordova":"none"};</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/5e974726f55e28b0daf88c48237b1131c3d9b50e.js"></script>
            <title>api-rest</title>
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
```

Every script file it references are just this same file, so this is further evidence that every request is just given this response. I'm very confused since deploying the app with `meteor deploy appname.meteor.com` works perfectly, and there are no logs in the app's logfile.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or know how to begin debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

Use mup: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up.

Diginatocean's guide might be outdated, never worked or both. Overall it seems too complicated for such a simple task.